# Convert Azure KeyVault Secret to RSACng or RSACryptoServiceProvider

Tags: c#, azure, encryption, rsa, azure-keyvault

**Edit/Add**: I have generated Keys (and Secrets and Certs) in Azure KeyVault.  I have not uploaded or stored anything I have created.  Everything in my KeyVault is Azure-Generated.

In part of my code, I am retrieving Keys and Secrets using the KeyVaultClient, like so:

```
var azureClient = new KeyVaultClient(...);
var azureSecret = await azureClient.GetSecretAsync(...);
var privateKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(azureSecret.Value);
```

This works successfully.  I can even create an `X509Certificate2` using that value.  Essentially, this is my flow:

- Get the Secret from Azure KeyVault
- Convert the `SecretBundle` Value (Base64) to Bytes
- Create an `X509Certificate2` from the Bytes
- `GetRSAPublicKey` and `GetRSAPrivateKey` from the cert.
- Successfully Encrypt and Decrypt data using `RSACng`

But then I asked myself... why am I passing key bytes to build a cert... then getting the key from the cert and discarding the cert?

So after a bit of research, I can't find a path from the Azure `SecretBundle` direct to either an `RSACryptoServiceProvider` object, or an `RSACng` object, even if through a `CngKey`.

In other code, I'm using `KeyVaultKeyResolver`, and wonder if there's a path through something like that (Though *Secret* based) to bypass X509 transformation.

As a side question, what data is represented by that `SecretBundle.Value`?  I'd assume it's something like "X.509 bytes", because I can use it to create an X509Cert2, and I can't deconstruct it into a private key.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Just to answer your question I was going through that route but no luck. I have done some research and found out that you can directly write the application/pkcs12 content to pfx files.

Here is a helper function you can use to convert Azure Keyvault Public/Private(secret) keys into a pfx file.

```
 public string GeneratePfxFile(string path, string certName, string rsaPublicKey, string privateKey)
    {
        var result = "";

        try
        {
            var certPath = Path.Combine(path, certName);
            if (File.Exists(certPath))
            {
                File.Delete(certPath);
            }

            var encodedText = Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey);


            //  write the private key to file
            using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(certPath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))
            {
                sourceStream.Write(encodedText, 0, encodedText.Length);

            }
            var publicPart = Convert.FromBase64String(rsaPublicKey);

            using (var stream = new FileStream(certPath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: false))
            {
                stream.Write(publicPart, 0, publicPart.Length);

            }
            result = "Certificate File is created";
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            result = $"Error: {e.Message}";
        }
        return result;
    }
```

*the stream writing is very crude but you can come up with an optimised solution.